# How to recreate the preview from Instagram's media_preview raw data?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, instagram, decode

If you get JSON data from Instagram's API you will find a `media_preview` key, the value of which is some Base64-encoded data. It really looks like some very small preview binary data. Maybe compressed.

Take [this post](https://www.instagram.com/p/5nWsoNvHX4/) for example. It's just a black square and its preview is very small. Its JSON contains
`data['graphql']['media_preview'] = "ACoq5miiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/Z"`

I could not reverse the code and find out how Instagram uses this data. What should I do to create a preview from this data?

I am not good at understanding minified js, but I think it draws blurred preview for "sensitive content" on a dynamically created canvas.

> Here is a [post](https://www.instagram.com/p/BgwalephZYo) with some sensitive content (medical) as an example

**Update:** I've noticed that b64decoded data always starts with `00 2A 2A` and ends with `FF D9`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've debugged a few lines of code and compiled this function for you. `media_preview` part of data is so small because full jpeg header already available in code as `jpegtpl` in my example:

```js
function ig_media_preview(base64data) {
 var jpegtpl = "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",
  t = atob(base64data),
  p = t.slice(3).split(""),
  o = t.substring(0, 3).split("").map(function(e) {
   return e.charCodeAt(0)
  }),
  c = atob(jpegtpl).split("");
 c[162] = String.fromCharCode(o[1]);
 c[160] = String.fromCharCode(o[2]);
 return base64data ? "data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(c.concat(p).join("")) : null
};
      
var data = "ACoq5miiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/Z";
var uri = ig_media_preview(data);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="' + uri + '">');
```

Comment: Try this: https://www.instagram.com/p/BgwalephZYo/  -> "ACoqg2t2br70wlv72aVYysgfaWUDHBz2x0qBrd9+4DjOfwzWXKVced1HWm8gnceT04pykA/WhpoLlmNKsbRVMOyhicf7OOv41B5z+ppJXKuIEB4q3b2m5sMO2cdM1TVhxuyOc5FakdqBh4mZTjhmOR+uP0rSUraBCKerKlzAI8OnRuMHqD/hVIsVx61cknlUlZCHB9Oh+npVPC9eefenG7VmTO19CxFI3JJ57cUwqD2/nUe/PC4o2vTUbbk83YkRWLY7eh6D3qzLKIh5a4b1I/zxVZjyfwqGPp+NDjd+Q1Jone4Z+AABTAoA9D+n0/zxSilrSxIhXPB4pm0VNn5B+NMpLULH/9k=" -- it makes damaged jpeg

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen Looks like you missed `c[162]` and `c[160]` manipulation in your `python` example, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes it seems like `header[160] = data[2]` and `header[162] = data[1]`. 
`data[0]` is useless. So final data is `header + data[3:]`