# Decode Instagram based64 media_preview using Python

Tags: python, instagram, decode

One of Instagram post fields is media_preview which is a... preview of the image, encoded to Base64 but in a special form.

I'd like to decode this media_preview using Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick "translation" based on this thread:
[How to recreate the preview from Instagram's media_preview raw data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625771/how-to-recreate-the-preview-from-instagrams-media-preview-raw-data)

```
import base64

def ig_media_preview(base64data):
    var_jpegtpl ="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"
    t = base64.b64decode(base64data)
    t=str(t,'latin1')
    p = list(t[3:])
    o = [ord(x) for x in t[0:3]]
    decodec = base64.b64decode(var_jpegtpl)
    c = list(str(decodec, 'latin1'))
    c[162] = chr(o[1])
    c[160] = chr(o[2])
    w = c.copy()
    w.extend(p)
    encodew = base64.b64encode(bytes("".join(w), 'latin1'))
    return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + str(encodew, 'latin1') if base64data else None

def main():
    data = "ACoq5miiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/Z"
    uri = ig_media_preview(data)
    assert uri == "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```